# How to print a different symbol depending on a value?

Tags: c, if-statement, logical-operators, logical-or

I have been tasked to create a program that displays a `-` or a `+` depending on a value from a function.

To make it a little more clear, the output, for a few different parts, should look something like this;

```
07.87 |----+---
12.97 |----+----+---
02.79 |---
```

Essentially, every 5th symbol should be a `+`, where the others are `-`. The maximum value that could appear is 15.

So far I have this, but its not working;

```
if (distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1) == 5 || 10 || 15){
     printf("+");
 }
 else{
    printf("-");
 }
```

What am I doing wrong? If you need more information, feel free to ask.

Comment: Your condition `distance(...) == 5 || 10 || 15` is equal to `(distance(...) == 5) || 10 || 15`, which will always be true.

Comment: In C you can't chain comparisons like that. Suggest, say `if((d = distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1) == 5) || d == 10 || d == 15)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see, that explains my wrong output. How would I fix it?

Comment: @JoeLigm what about using `distance(...) % 5 == 0`

Comment: Think a little about what I wrote, especially about that you only compare the result of `distance()` with `5`. How could you compare it to the other values?

Comment: @JUSHJUSH I tried that but as my distance() is of type double, it won't allow it. I get an error

Comment: "distance() is of type double" makes those direct equality comparisons invalid almost immediately. Floating point arithmetic on binary computers will lead to rounding errors, which means you will seldom get an exact value that you can use for exact equality comparison. Either try to use integers in your calculations, use rounding or truncating of the floating point result to an integer, or use an *epsilon* to compare about equal to instead of exact equal to.

Comment: Okay I see, I am new to C so I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2):

This condition

```
distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1) == 5 || 10 || 15
```

is equivalent to

```
( distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1) == 5 ) || ( 10 ) || ( 15 )
```

As `10` and `15` are not equal to zero then the condition will always evaluate to true.

You can rewrite it the following way

```
int value = distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1);

if ( value != 0 && value % 5 == 0 ){
     printf("+");
 }
 else{
    printf("-");
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention distance() is of type double, so it is giving me an error saying `error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'double' and 'int')`

Comment: @JoeLigm Reread the code snippet I showed. The variable value is of the type int.

Comment: @JoeLigm You can also use standard rounding functions to convert a double value to an integer value.

Comment: Perhaps `printf` could be simplified to `putchar`?

Answer (score 1):

It is really unclear what is the connection of your `distance` function with 'every fifth symbol'. However it may be you are looking for 'modulo' and this may be what you want:

```
int dist = distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1);
if (dist % 5 == 0){
  printf("+");
}
else{
  printf("-");
}
```

Alternatively if 0 is not needed:

```
int dist = distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1);
if (dist != 0 && dist % 5 == 0){
  printf("+");
}
else{
  printf("-");
}
```

If not, then you need to give us more information on what it is you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your input. There is no real connection between the two, the distance is measured in km, so the task wants to visualise distance too, with `-` and `+`. My best guess  is that `+` is used to make reading a little easier

Answer (score 0):

```
int dist=distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1); 
for(int i=0; i<dist;i++){ 
printf("%c", (dist % 5 == 0) ? '+' : '-'); 
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation why your example is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Drop this down to one simple line, using modulo (`%`) and a ternary operator:

```
 printf("%c", distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1)%5 ? '-' : '+');
```

---

### Explanation:

```
printf("%c",...);
```

Will print one character from the parameters.  This will end up being either `'-'` or `'+'`.

The expression `distance(lat_2, long_2, LAT_1, LONG_1) % 5` will be `false` when the value is 5, 10, 15, 20, etc...., and will be `true` for all other values.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot actually check the distance with 5 or 10 or 15 as you have done.

What is required is to continuously decrease the distance until it becomes less than zero. And print `+` every 5th time, else print `-`

A sample code is below.

```
int count = 0;
double distance;
...
while (distance >= 0)
{
    distance -= 1;
    count++;
    if (count%5 == 0)
        printf ("+");
    else
        printf ("-");
}
```

You should note that since `double` is used there is always a possibility of errors being introduced because of floating point operations. For small values and precision as in your example, I do not think there should be any problems.

Comment: Will this not produce a never ending output as distance() is always greater than 0?

Comment: `distance` is decremented in the loop.